# Create and update secrets on AWS if they already exists with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to create secrets for a microservice using Terraform, and I want to initialize the secrets with some values from my Terraform configuration, but I also want to allow adding secrets manually.

This is what I initially tried.

```
locals {
  secret_name = "${var.environment}/microservices/${var.project_name}/secrets"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secrets" {
  name        = local.secret_name
  description = "Secrets for ${var.project_name} microservice."
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "credentials" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.id

  secret_string = jsonencode(
    {
      ENV            = var.environment,
      DYNAMODB_TABLE = var.dynamo_db_table_name
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY = var.aws_key
      AWS_SECRET_KEY = var.aws_secret
    }
  )
}
```

the problem with the code above is that if a manual secret is added, the code with override those secrets, therefore I updated my code to fetch the secrets and merge them together, as shown below.

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret-version" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.id
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "credentials" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.id

  secret_string = jsonencode(merge(
    try(jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret-version.secret_string), {}),
    {
      ENV            = var.environment,
      DYNAMODB_TABLE = var.dynamo_db_table_name
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY = var.aws_key
      AWS_SECRET_KEY = var.aws_secret
    }
  ))
}
```

the above code was working fine, but then I was working with a second environment, and I encounter an issue. I cannot fetch data from a secret that does not exist.

```
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Secrets Manager Secret "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-2:***:secret:staging/microservices/***/secrets-HRCPqx" Version "AWSCURRENT" not found
│ 
│   with module.ms_secrets.data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret-version,
│   on ../modules/secrets/main.tf line 15, in data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret-version":
│   15: data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secret-version" {
│ 
╵
```

So basically my question is, how can I allow the creation of a secret with default values or empty and then fetch data from an already created secret and merge them together?

Comment: Terraform does not do *"... if resource does not exist yet"*. A data source expects a thing to be there and a resource creates one and assume it was not already there. The only way around this is to [import existing resources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/import) into your state and drop the *"... if not exist"* logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to include the [ignore_changes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes) on the `secret_string` field. This configuration ensures that secrets are initially created using the default value. The manual changes made to the environment will not be overridden during subsequent code releases.

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "credentials" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secrets.id

  secret_string = jsonencode(
    {
      ENV            = var.environment,
      DYNAMODB_TABLE = var.dynamo_db_table_name
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY = var.aws_key
      AWS_SECRET_KEY = var.aws_secret
    }
  )

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [secret_string]
  }
}
```

p.s. This way, you will have to update the secret values manually to all the environments.

Comment: I believe that this could work as well. Thank you!